# Where to unbind static event handlers?

Tags: c#, .net, events, static

Let's say, I have a static class `A` which has a static event:

```
public static class A
{
    public static event Action SampleEvent;

    //other members of A ...
}
```

I have a static class `B`, which binds to that event:

```
public static class B
{
    public static void DoSomeJob()
    {
        // To do some job, I need to bind to A.SampleEvent
        // A.SampleEvent +=       
        // After the job is done, I still need the event handler, bound to A.SampleEvent, to update some thing in B
    }

    //other members of B ...
}
```

The question is, what is a good place to unbound from `A.SampleEvent`? Unfortunately, there is no destructor for static classes.

Comment: Can you unbind as soon as the event fires, IE within the event handler itself?

Comment: If you can't deterministically determine when to unsubscribe from that event, then don't. If you can: then do at the time you can. A destructor (or finalizer as it should be called in c#) in non-static classes is not deterministic: you don't know when it will be called: you can't even guarantee it's going to be called at all (that's why `IDisposable` exists).

Comment: Furthermore, having a non weak local delegate subscribed on an event is a way to be sure that an object will never be collected (thus its finalizer never called), so unsubscribing there is just absurd

Comment: Is anything bad going to happen, if I don't unsubscribe at all?

Comment: @ArtemKachanovskyi *just* by not unsubscribing, nope. Just make sure that if `DoSomeJob` is called more than once, it doesn't subscribe more than once (unless that's a requirement), either by having a check, or by doing `A.SampleEvent -= Whatever; A.SampleEvent+=Whatever;`. The first unsubscribing will do nothing if it was not already subscribed (won't throw exceptions or anything)

Comment: No reason to be afraid of memory leaks?

Comment: What would leak there? A static object can't leak because it'll never be garbage collected: it'll be in memory from the moment it's created till the application ends. You can't free the memory from static objects. A "memory leak" happens when you (or the GC) don't free up the instances of your objects, but that doesn't happen with static classes

Comment: Thank you. I just wasn't sure about static classes.

Answer (score 1):

One place would be directly in the handler after it updated `B`:

```
public static class B
{
    public static void DoSomeJob()
    {
        // To do some job, I need to bind to A.SampleEvent
        A.SampleEvent += A_SampleEvent;
        // do job
    }

    private static void A_SampleEvent(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        // update B
        A.SampleEvent -= A_SampleEvent;
    }

    //other members of B ...
}
```